# Conflicting happens when generating two hashmaps in java

Tags: java, hashmap

I have two text, I make tokenizing and removing stop words then I make lemmatization then I generate an hashmap that contains the lemma and its frequency in the text.

when I apply above steps on one text everything works fine like below:

```
String train = "hamza was studying hamza studied yesterday";
    String test = "hamza is swimming today";

    sportBag = bagOfWords.Bag(lemmatize.Lemmatize(tokenizeAndRemoveStopWords.RemoveStopWords(train)));

    //testBag = bagOfWords.Bag(lemmatize.Lemmatize(tokenizeAndRemoveStopWords.RemoveStopWords(test)));
    System.out.println("hashmap for train");

    for (String name : sportBag.keySet()) {
        String key = name;
        int value = sportBag.get(name);
        System.out.println(key + " " + value);
    }

    System.out.println("hashmap for test");
    for (String name : testBag.keySet()) {
        String key = name;
        int value = testBag.get(name);
        System.out.println(key + " " + value);
    }
```

and the output is as expected

```
hashmap for train
yesterday 1
study 2
hamza 2
```

The problem happens when I generate two hashmaps like below:

```
String train = "hamza was studying hamza studied yesterday";
    String test = "hamza is swimming today";

    sportBag = bagOfWords.Bag(lemmatize.Lemmatize(tokenizeAndRemoveStopWords.RemoveStopWords(train)));

    testBag = bagOfWords.Bag(lemmatize.Lemmatize(tokenizeAndRemoveStopWords.RemoveStopWords(test)));
    System.out.println("hashmap for train");

    for (String name : sportBag.keySet()) {
        String key = name;
        int value = sportBag.get(name);
        System.out.println(key + " " + value);
    }

    System.out.println("hashmap for test");
    for (String name : testBag.keySet()) {
        String key = name;
        int value = testBag.get(name);
        System.out.println(key + " " + value);
    }
```

and here the problem happen

```
hashmap for train
yesterday 1
swimming 1
study 2
today 1
hamza 2
hashmap for test
yesterday 1
swimming 1
study 2
today 1
hamza 2
```

here is Bag method :

```
public Map<String, Integer> words = new HashMap<>();

/**
 * Constructor.
 *
 * @param wordsList
 * @return
 */
public Map<String, Integer> Bag(List<String> wordsList) {
    for (int i = 0; i < wordsList.size(); i++) {
        int freq = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < wordsList.size(); j++) {
            if (wordsList.get(j).equals(wordsList.get(i))) {
                freq++;
            }
        }
        if (!words.containsKey(wordsList.get(i))) {
            words.put(wordsList.get(i), freq);
        }
    }
    return words;
}
```

why this happens?

Comment: can't really say without the code of `bagOfWords.Bag`. looks like it reuses the map inside and just adds the words from the second string

Comment: Agree with @Nir. Looks like `bagOfWords.Bag` is the culprit. If you are using instance variable in the method change it to local variable (local variable)

Comment: @NirLevy, I just edit my question and add bag method that generates the hashmap

Comment: Why does "Bag" return a *field* words? Why not just make words local to the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same instance of the bagOfWords for sportBag and testBag. And since your **.Bag** method never clears the map, it tries to add values to the map with existing values.

You have 2 options here:

- Clear the map at the start of the .Bag() method.
- Create the new instance of the bagOfWords every time you need to generate the HashMap.

Comment: I have clear the map and created new instance of bagOfWords and the that doesn't solve the problem.... here is the output>>>>>

hashmap for train
yesterday 1
study 2
hamza 2
hashmap for test
yesterday 1
swimming 1
study 2
today 1
hamza 3

Comment: @HamzaDabjan are you sure that you created the new instance? 
If yes, instead of that try to Add `words = new HashMap<>();` at the start of the Bag method and see what happens.

Comment: @HamzaDabjan where are you clearing the map, and where are you creating a new map?

Comment: @matt I clear the map in the start of the Bag method, and I create a new map in my class where main method is located

Comment: @CliveLewis yes I did that and the same output is shown

Comment: @HamzaDabjan Then the issue is somewhere in the classes of lemmatize or tokenizeAndRemoveStopWords. One of those classes also stores the terms and doesn't clear them.

Comment: @HamzaDabjan you'll need to update your code. If you clear the map at the beginning of the Bag method, you are still using the *same map* for both train and test. You should delete `public Map<String, Integer> words = new HashMap<>();` and put `Map<String, Integer> words = new HashMap<>()` inside of your Bag method so that everything that calls it will get a new instance.

Comment: @CliveLewis Thanks a lot, I have clear variables in other classes and it works finally, thanks for your help again

Comment: @matt thanks for your help, I have clear variables in other classes and it works